# Saving js variables for Lat/Lng in a google map

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, google-maps

I have a map with a marker which can be dragged.  Once the user drags the marker, I get new coordinates.

I try to make an AJAX call and put them into the session, but for some reason that does not seem to be working.

The test page is here: http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/parks/add_trailhead.php

And the ajax I have looks like this:

```
$lat = $_GET['lat'];
$lng = $_GET['lng'];

$_SESSION['trailhead_lat'] = $lat;
$_SESSION['trailhead_lng'] = $lng;
```

My question is really, how do I save the lat/lng from the dragged marker location so that I can save to as the coordinates when the form is submitted?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Were those `<blink>` tags supposed to be part of the code sample, or were you just trying to make the code blink? If they were part of the code sample, I'll add them back in (with prejudice). :)

Comment: No, I was hoping the blink tags would make the code look better.  Maybe I am missing something :) The way you did it looks right.

Comment: Right on. I crack up any time I see `<blink>` tags anywhere. As an FYI: to format the code, you can highlight all of it and click the `{}` button above the markup editor.

Comment: Can't you just grab the coordinates via the gmap JS API and stuff those into a hidden input field inside your form?

Comment: That is sort of what I am also trying to do, but how?

Comment: Essentially, I'd be happy to be able to put the new coordinates into the form as hidden fields.  But I am not sure how to do it.  It is an html form and the values are in JS.  I am not strong enough in JS to know how to get this right.  Any help with this would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion in the comments to put the variable into the hidden form fields was much better.  Thanks!